# Jmeter 1 Thread Group and Multiple HttpRequest

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, api-testing, rest-api

I have the following Jmeter configuration where I have

1 Thread Group with Number of Threads 1 and under this 4 HttpRequest I have defined. The loop count is `forever`.

[image]

My question is how will my requests be fired ? Since I defined `1 as number of threads` in our thread group , will it fire the above 4 requests sequentially or parallel ?

If I had defined `2 as number of threads` in our thread group , then how would request would have been fired then ?

To make things simple, assume ramp up time is 0.

Answer (score 1):

> Since I defined 1 as number of threads in our thread group , will it
>   fire the above 4 requests sequentially or parallel ?

As said in the [manual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#samplers),

> samplers tell JMeter to send requests to a server and wait for a
>   response. They are processed in the order they appear in the tree.

Regarding

> If I had defined 2 as number of threads in our thread group

Eacher thread executes the requests in sequence independently. JMeter only takes care of ensuring the ramp-up period. If the requests from the first thread take longer than the ramp-up period, you will have some parallelism (overlap) between the two threads.

Answer (score 0):

Each JMeter thread (virtual user) executes [samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [logic controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)) **sequentially**. Each thread is **independent**

You can see which thread is doing what and when by adding [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function as the prefix/postfix  for your Sampler labels and adding i.e. [View Results in Table](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-listeners-part-1-basic-display-formats/) listener to your Test Plan

[image]